# Can not dismiss keyboard iOS. Nothing works

Tags: ios, keyboard, dismiss

I'm new in iOS Development for iPhone. I can not dismiss keyboard, nothing works. Please help me, maybe I didn't notice anything?

My .h file:

```
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@end
```

My .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *) textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: Sorry, when I've been writing code, accidentally pressed enter, please wait for a minute I'll copy my code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi this is a simple mistake. You have not set the delegate. You can do this by..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    textField.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add `textField.delegate = self;` to your `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to set the delegate for textField. Inside your storyboard or nib file, drag your UITextField's delegate to your ViewController.